# How to iterate over groups from cogroup to print key and its values (per group)?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am learning spark and have the following code:

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("key1", 5),("key2", 4),("key4", 1)))
val grouped = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)
grouped.collect()
```

Output:

```
Array[(String, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]))] = Array(
  (key3,(CompactBuffer(1),CompactBuffer())), 
  (key1,(CompactBuffer(1, 3),CompactBuffer(5))),
  (key4,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(1))),
  (key2,(CompactBuffer(2),CompactBuffer(4))))
```

How to iterate the values in a way that I get the output as follows:

```
key1,1,3,5

key2,2,4

key4,1

key3,1
```

below is the code i have tried.

```
val z=grouped.map{x=>
 val key=x._1
 val value=x._2
 val source1=value._1
 val final_value=source1.map{if(value._1>=1) value._1}
 (key,final_value)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you replace `cogroup` with [join](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@join[W](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,W)],partitioner:org.apache.spark.Partitioner):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,(V,W))]) that would give you a sequence of pairs with a key and its values (as a collection) as follows:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("key1", 1), ("key1", 3), ("key2", 2), ("key3", 1)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("key1", 5),("key2", 4),("key4", 1)))
val joined = rdd1.join(rdd2)
scala> joined.foreach(println)
(key2,(2,4))
(key1,(1,5))
(key1,(3,5))

// or using Spark SQL's Dataset API
scala> joined.toDF("key", "values").show
+----+------+
| key|values|
+----+------+
|key1| [1,5]|
|key1| [3,5]|
|key2| [2,4]|
+----+------+
```

---

If however you want to stay with `cogroup` to learn Spark's RDD API, you'd print `grouped.collect` as follows:

```
// I assume grouped is the value after cogroup+collect
// just because it's easier to demo the solution
val grouped = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).collect
scala> grouped.foreach(println)
(key1,(CompactBuffer(1, 3),CompactBuffer(5)))
(key2,(CompactBuffer(2),CompactBuffer(4)))
(key3,(CompactBuffer(1),CompactBuffer()))
(key4,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(1)))

// the solution
grouped.
  map { case (k, (g1, g2)) => (k, g1 ++ g2) }.
  map { case (k, vs) => s"$k,${vs.mkString(",")}" }.
  foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the esiest way is to convert to Data frame and group by key and collect the values as list.

```
 val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("key1", 3),("key1", 5),("key2", 4),("key4", 1))).toDF("K", "V")
 rdd2.groupBy("K").agg(collect_list($"V")).show
```

Hope this helps